# Fixed position sidebar and dropdown menu near it

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position

Here is my code

html

```
<nav>
<ul class="main">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hover Me 1</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">child last</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</nav>
<div class="content"></div>
```

css

```
html,
  body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  width: 300px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:20px 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
}

.main li:hover {
  background: red
}

.main ul {
  display: none;
}

nav:hover {
  overflow: auto;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.main li:hover ul {
  top: 0;
  padding:20px 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height:100%;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 270px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 99;
  background:#333;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 350px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

The problem is that when you hover on `Hover Me 1` you need see dropdown menu near sidebar. On windows its working fine, but in iOS and OsX its dont work! I dont know how to get rid of this problem.. May be is there any solution preferably on CSS, but if not - I am ready for jQuery..
Please tell me something, I already have a headache from this problem :(

Here is [JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bqy66jf0/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use position absolute on the sub menu and position relative on the parent li, something like this:

```
.main > li {
position:relative;
}
.main li:hover ul {
position: absolute;
left:300px;
top:0;
}
```

Comment: Try your code yourself please, before posting here. It appears horizontal scroll on sidebar, and hidden menu positioning near it INSIDE sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your code responsive and you can do this by adding `media` tag in your css for different screen size **ios screen size** then modify your code according to **ios screen size** 
like this mockup
[image]
see this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/96qtntgj/)